# How to get first row in Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can i create a method in my model below that consist of first value of pages?

> I want my cover method to get he first instance of pages.

**Here's my model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
   protected $guarded = [];

   public function pages()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('\App\Page');
   }

   public function cover()
   {
       //first page of pages here
   }

}
```

Comment: `return $this->pages()->first()`?

Comment: it returns an error, App\Book::cover must return a relationship instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the first() method on the relationship

```
public function cover()
{
    return $this->pages()->first();
}
```

Comment: i try it but it return this error , App\Book::cover must return a relationship instance.

Comment: You have to call it on an instance of book, for example: App\Book::first()->cover()

Comment: you have to use () , optherwise laravel tries to look for a relationship

Comment: i access it as method with () not as property but it return this: 
src="http://ebook.dev/{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;book_id&quot;:5,&quot;page&quot;:&quot;uploads\/page\/150693014959d1ede50f81d.jpg&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2017-10-02 07:42:29&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2017-10-02 07:42:29&quot;}"

Comment: it returns all properties not just the page.

Comment: here's my code. $books = Book::paginate(4); and in the view i used foreach to display each books.

Comment: i got it. using this one. src="{{ url($book->cover()->page) }}". thanks guys.